# vertical alignment when content changes

Tags: html, richfaces, ajax4jsf

Hi I'm trying to align vertically two elements

The code is

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <a4j:outputPanel layout="block">
            <h:form>
                <h:inputText id="text1" label="text1" value="#{opBean1.text}">
                    <f:validateLength maximum="10" />
                    <a4j:ajax event="keyup" execute="@this" render="out1" onerror="return false;" />
                </h:inputText><br/>
                <h:outputText id="out1" rendered="#{not empty opBean1.text}" value="Approved Text: #{opBean1.text}" />
            </h:form>
        </a4j:outputPanel>

        <a4j:outputPanel layout="block">
            <h:form>
                <h:inputText id="text2" label="text2" value="#{opBean1.text2}">
                    <f:validateLength maximum="10" />
                    <a4j:ajax event="keyup" execute="@this" render="out2" onerror="return false;" />
                </h:inputText><br/>
                <h:outputText id="out2" rendered="#{not empty opBean1.text2}" value="Approved Text: #{opBean1.text2}" />
            </h:form>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
</h:panelGrid>
```

As you can see,
the `<h:panelGrid>` contains two columns.
Each column has a `<a4j:outputPanel>` element.

The problem is that the vertical size of the `<a4j:outputPanel>` can change.
(The `<h:outputText id="xxx" rendered="#{not empty opBean1.xxx}" value="Approved Text: #{opBean1.xxx}" />` element is only rendered if the xxx value is not empty in the managed bean opBean1)

So if I enter some text in the first a4j panel, it will contain two lines vertically, whereas the other a4j panel will contain only one.
Therefore, the second panel's inputText field will not be aligne anymore with the first panel's text field.

I know this might be hard to understand without any graphical representation, so I'll show you what I mean :
Before entering text:

```
inputText1  inputText2
```

After entering text:

```
inputText1
            inputText2
outputText1
```

I would like it to be:

```
inputText1 inputText2

outputText1
```

EDIT (sorry for the identation ... I don´t know how to make it better)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>

<title>Mission Page</title><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/FlightFAQ/rfRes/skinning.ecss.jsf?db=eAHjW!XqPQAE!QKS" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/FlightFAQ/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.jsf?ln=javax.faces&amp;stage=Development"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/FlightFAQ/javax.faces.resource/jquery.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/FlightFAQ/javax.faces.resource/richfaces.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/FlightFAQ/javax.faces.resource/richfaces-base-component.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/FlightFAQ/javax.faces.resource/richfaces-event.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/FlightFAQ/javax.faces.resource/message.js.jsf?ln=org.richfaces"></script><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/FlightFAQ/rfRes/msg.ecss.jsf?db=eAHjW!XqPQAE!QKS&amp;ln=org.richfaces" /></head><body><table>

<tbody>

<tr>

<td><div id="j_idt6">

<form id="j_idt7" name="j_idt7" method="post" action="/FlightFAQ/debug.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

<input type="hidden" name="j_idt7" value="j_idt7" />

<span style="font-weight: bold;">Name: </span><input id="j_idt7:clientName" type="text" name="j_idt7:clientName" onblur="av_aea6d620643bb708da4bf66b58ae27d6(event,&quot;j_idt7:clientName&quot;,this)" />

<br /><span class="rf-msg " id="j_idt7:j_idt10"></span><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="-6739208697542802203:-2950524051097537124" autocomplete="off" />

</form></div></td>

<td><div id="j_idt11">

<form id="j_idt12" name="j_idt12" method="post" action="/FlightFAQ/debug.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

<input type="hidden" name="j_idt12" value="j_idt12" />

<span style="font-weight: bold;">Contact: </span><input id="j_idt12:contact" type="text" name="j_idt12:contact" /><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="-6739208697542802203:-2950524051097537124" autocomplete="off" />

</form></div></td>

</tr>

</tbody>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/FlightFAQ/javax.faces.resource/richfaces-csv.js.jsf?ln=org.richfaces"></script><script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

window.av_aea6d620643bb708da4bf66b58ae27d6=function(event,id,e,da){var p={da:da,v:[{f:RichFaces.csv.validateRequired,p:{} ,m:{"detail":"name cannot be null","severity":0,"summary":"name cannot be null"} }]};

RichFaces.csv.validate(event,id,e,p);

}

$(document).ready(function() {

new RichFaces.ui.Message("j_idt7:j_idt10",{"forComponentId":"j_idt7:clientName","showSummary":false,"showDetail":true} )

});



//]]>

</script></body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're asking people to troubleshoot a client-side problem, but you are only showing your server-side code.

Comment: what else can I show, beside the small "visual" example at the end ?

Comment: Show your HTML + CSS that this generates. That's what the browser sees and that's what we need to see too.